# Visual Studio Data Compare - Query completed with Errors

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssms, data-comparison

I am trying to update a db using the Data Compare functionality in VS.

Once I setup which tables I want to update I can use **Write Updates** and my DB is updated.

However, when I Export to a .sql file and try to run it from SSMS I don't get anything in the
Messages window and I don't have a Results window.  At the bottom it says Query completed with errors.

How do I view the errors and/or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the generated file was too big.  SSMS was choking on it for some reason

Ran `sqlcmd -S (local) -i C:\DataUpdateFile.sql` and it worked fine.

Comment: the brackets around `(local)` are what helped me